# mySQL database structure

Tags: java, mysql, sql, rdbms, arrays

I'm kinda stuck in a tricky situation with the mySQL DB design for my webservice.The DB had initially this Structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Disease` (
   `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `Age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `Descriptin` text NOT NULL,
   `Sex` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `Ethnicity` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Name`,`Sex`,`Ethnicity`),
    KEY `Sex` (`Sex`),
    KEY `Ethnicity` (`Ethnicity`)
     ) 

  ALTER TABLE `Disease`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `Disease_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Sex`) REFERENCES `Sex` (`Sex`)     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Disease_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Ethnicity`) REFERENCES `Ethnicity` (`Ethnicity`)     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

So basically Disease(**Name**,Age,Description,**Sex**, **Ethnicity** ) Where Sex and Ethnicity are foreign keys to two tables named Sex and Ethnicity because they can have more than one value.

Now to the question I need to add another Column called Symptoms which will be multivalued but I cant declare it as a foreign key, what i need is this:

example of a row

```
Disease(Name="DiseaseName",Age="40",Description="is caused by...",Sex="male",Ethnicity="Caucasian",Symptoms"Headache,sorethroat,fever")
```

So basically i need Symptoms to contain a String of Array but apparently I cant do it since its an RDBMS

Thanks all for you time and efforts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. Instead, normalize your data model: Make a new table "Symptoms", constrained with foreign key "Disease", and make one record for each symptom.

Whenever you start thinking about putting collections of data into a single field, you're effectively trying to build your own mini database *inside* the database. Thinking that you can outperform and outwit your RDBMS is optimistic at best and most likely leads to unmaintainable code later on.

By the way, does `Sex` really have to be looked up in a separate table? For micro-categories like that you might like to consider some sort of enum type.

Comment: Yes i have actually implemented two other columns Sex and Ethnicity the way you said, the issue is that they don't solve my need. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: @Rosa: Well, how about an enum?

Comment: Actually just adopted enum for Sex :) and it works thanks! But again for the original question it wont work, since using enum you can store one value per record

Comment: @Rosa: You mean for the symptoms? No, sure, you cannot use enums for symptoms, least of all because there isn't a bounded, predetermined set of symptoms. As I said, make a separate "Symptoms" table and refer each symptom to a disease.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the "array of strings" you're looking for by normalizing your data.  Add a new key column to your 'Disease' table.  Then create a child table called 'Symptom'.  Insert a record for each string with a foreign key back to the 'Disease' table parent record.

Comment: Let me explain what i want to accomplaish: A query on table Disease will match the Sex,Ethnicity and age of a patient and the "list" of symptoms he has and then return the name of the disease.How could i do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't notice you misspelled *Description* in your table creation query.

Comment: actually the original is in Italian, just changed it in English here for better comprehension, Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need a m:n relation:

- Table: Disease

  - Name
  - Sex
  - Ethnicity
- Table: Symptoms

  - ID
  - Name
- Table: Disease_has_Symptoms

  - Name (FK to Disease)
  - Sex (FK to Disease)
  - Ethnicity (FK to Disease)
  - ID (FK to Symptoms)

(Maybe it's easier to add an ID-column to Disease and reference that inside Disease_has_Symptoms)